# Django - First project - runserver is an invalid syntax

Tags: python, django

I decided to try developing on python with django, while python is new to me right now.

[I'm using Windows 7 64bit]

Then, i installed python 2.7, added C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts; to PATH variable.
Next, i installed Eclipse Classic (last version) and installed PyDev, and Django.

I created my first project on Eclipse as a Django project but couldn't run it.
I'm trying (Right click on my project)-> Run as -> PyDev: Django, and i have the following console log:

```
Validating models...

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Matan\workspace\FirstSample\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 80, in run
```

and the list goes on...

So i tried to run the project with the python console, using:

```
import Django

manage.py runserver
```

and i have the following syntax error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  manage.py runserver
                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the problem with running my project ? How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Edit:
After trying to run the project with the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver on the project directory, i receive the following traceback log: Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <dja ngo.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x000000 0002688748>> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver. py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 266,  in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin e 23, in get_validation_errors
    from django.db import models, connection   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 40, in <modul e>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in
__geta ttr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 92, in
__getitem
__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 24, in load_back end
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im port_module
    __import__(name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 16 , in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No mo dule named MySQLdb
```

Comment: Run `python manage.py runserver` at a system command prompt, not in the Python console.

Comment: After running the command you mentioned, i received the following error: 
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <dja
ngo.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x000000
0002688748>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 266,

Comment: we'll need the entire traceback (please edit your post to include it instead of fighting with the comment area).  The most important part of the traceback is the bottom part...

Comment: @thebjorn my post is updated with the full traceback.

Comment: It says you need to install the MySQLdb client library if you've set up your settings file to use MySQL as a database. You can get a win64 version from here: http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

Comment: @thebjorn Thank you, it's working right now. I had to install MySQLdb client and re-configure my sql connection settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error loading MySQLdb module: No mo dule named MySQLdb

You have configured your settings to you MySQL but you have not installed `MySQL-python`:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that will work with a Python 2.7 + win64 install :-(   see my comment under the question above for a link though...

Comment: I don't think those installers will play nice with virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Download the pre-compiled [python-mysql package](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) for Windows, install it, then run the command again.

While you are there, you might as well also install [setuptools](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

You must be in the project directory to run the python manage.py runserver command.  You also need to (1) set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include your project directory's *parent* and (2) set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to *yourproject.settings*

If you've done it correctly, you should be able to go to an unrelated directory (i.e. not your project directory) and do the following import in a python shell:

```
c:\temp> python
...
>>> from django.conf import settings
```

the settings module that is imported should then be the one in your project directory...